# need to rename many files in directory using sed and find

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to rename all files named *-6.0.dll with *-6.1.dll
I tried:

```
 find . -name '*-6.0.dll*' -exec mv {} $(echo {} | sed -e 's/-6.0.dll/-6.1.dll/g') \;
```

but this didn't work; the file names didn't change.

Any ideas?

Comment: the stuff in `$( ... )` only get executed once? There might be a way to quote this, but much easier to make a script that wraps your mv. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for x in *-6.0.dll; do y=$(echo $x | sed -e 's/-6\.0\.dll$/-6.1.dll/'); echo mv $x $y; done
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied the results are correct.

Comment: Thanks. But, the file names are not changed. Note: I am using Git bash on windows.

Comment: Right, you have to remove the `echo` to actually change the file names.  The `echo` is there for you to review the output before actually doing the move.

Comment: after taking out the caret in above, and escaping the dots, I got the mv commands to look correct, but still no files were modified.

Answer (score 1):

use this:
`find . -name '*-6.0.dll*' -exec sh -c 'mv {} $(echo {} | sed -e 's/\-6\.0\.dll/\-6\.1\.dll/g')' \;`

an explanation of using the `sh -c` vs `mv` can be found here http://linuxplayer.org/2010/05/shell-programming-trap-batch-rename-with-find

I also modified your regex, some of the characters need to be escaped for proper matching.